# Why am I getting a 404 error when trying to reach the taxonomy.php page without any terms, (Wordpress don't see taxonomy page)

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type, taxonomy

I'm trying to create taxonomy page so I created taxonomy with taxonomie taxonomy-nowe.php

but my WP don't see the page or I mess something with the rewrite URL? Can someone check my code and see if something I'm doing wrong. I did the flush the permalinks by save the Plain and then return to Post name permalinks. But I get not result.

I want to achive somethink like this: domain.pl/oferta/kopiarki/nowe

```
// custom post type
function td_devices_posttype() {
 $labels = array(
     'name'                => _x( 'Kopiarki', 'Ogólna nazwa wpisów', 'textdomain' ),
     'singular_name'       => _x( 'Kopiarka', 'Pojedyńcza nazwa wpisu', 'textdomain' ),
     'menu_name'           => esc_html__( 'Kopiarki', 'textdomain' ),
     'parent_item_colon'   => esc_html__( 'Rodzic', 'textdomain' ),
     'all_items'           => esc_html__( 'Wszystkie kopiarki', 'textdomain' ),
     'view_item'           => esc_html__( 'Wyświetl kopiarki', 'textdomain' ),
     'add_new_item'        => esc_html__( 'Dodaj nową kopiarkę', 'textdomain' ),
     'add_new'             => esc_html__( 'Dodaj nową', 'textdomain' ),
     'edit_item'           => esc_html__( 'Edytuj Kopiarkę', 'textdomain' ),
     'update_item'         => esc_html__( 'Zaktualizuj kopiarkę', 'textdomain' ),
     'search_items'        => esc_html__( 'Szukaj kopiarkę', 'textdomain' ),
     'not_found'           => esc_html__( 'Nie zanleziono', 'textdomain' ),
     'not_found_in_trash'  => esc_html__( 'Nie znaleziono w koszu', 'textdomain' )
 );
 $args = array(
     'label'               => esc_html__( 'kopiarki', 'textdomain' ),
     'description'         => esc_html__( 'Wszystkie kopiarki', 'textdomain' ),
     'labels'              => $labels,
     'taxonomies'          => array( 'nowe' ),
     'hierarchical'        => true,
     'public'              => true,
     'show_ui'             => true,
     'show_in_menu'        => true,
     'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
     'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
     'menu_position'       => 100,
     'can_export'          => true,
     'has_archive'         => true,
     'exclude_from_search' => false,
     'publicly_queryable'  => true,
     'query_var'           => true,
     'show_admin_column'   => true,
     'capability_type'     => 'page',
     'rewrite'             => array('slug' => 'oferta/kopiarki'),
     'supports'            => array( 'title','editor','thumbnail', 'custom-fields')
 );
 register_post_type( 'kopiarki', $args );
  //flush_rewrite_rules();
}
add_action( 'init', 'td_devices_posttype' );

// custom taxonomies new
function new_posttype_taxonomy() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                  => 'Nowe',
        'singular_name'         => 'Nowa',
        'search_items'          => 'Szukaj nowych',
        'all_items'             => 'Wszystkie nowe kopiarki',
        'parent_item'           => 'Rodzic',
        'parent_item_colon'     => 'Dwukropek elementu nadrzędnego:',
        'edit_item'             => 'Edytuj nową kopiarkę',
        'update_item'           => 'Zaktualizuj nową kopiarkę',
        'add_new_item'          => 'Dodaj nową kopiarkę',
        'new_item_name'         => 'Nowa nazwa kopiarki',
        'menu_name'             => 'Nowe'
    );

    $args = array (
        'hierarchical'          => true,
        'labels'                => $labels,
        'show_ui'               => true,
        'show_admin_column'     => true,
        'show_in_rest'          => true,
        'query_var'             => true,
        'rewrite'               => array(
      'slug'                    => 'nowe',
      'with_front'              => false,
    )
    );
    register_taxonomy( 'nowe', array( 'kopiarki' ), $args );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This post has been edited many times as, at the time, I didn't had all the information regarding the issue. I've since made extensive research on that subject. The following goes straight to the point and the answer.**

---

We have two goals here, getting the permalink structure to the following

`domain.com/_custom_post_type_/_taxonomy_/_term_/ ...`

And get the `taxonomy.php` to return an index of posts and terms associated to a specific taxonomy part a of custom post type instead of a `404.php` page.

---

> "When a visitor clicks on a hyperlink to category, tag or custom
> taxonomy, WordPress displays a page of posts in reverse chronological
> order filtered by that taxonomy."

*Source: @ https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/*

The default template used for taxonomies is `taxonomy.php`. These files let you target specific taxonomies or specific taxonomy terms. For example: `taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php` and `taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php`

In your case when you search for `./fruits/apples` you get all posts related to the term `apples` either displayed on either `taxonomy.php` or on `taxonomy-fruits.php` or finally on `taxonomy-fruits-aples.php`.
But what if you want to access `./fruits/`? **Why does accessing fruit gives back a `404.php` error?** Well because `taxonomy.php` was intended to displays posts against terms, not posts against taxonomies. **This is the normal and intended behaviour**.

*This goes back to 10 years ago https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13816, and multiple issues were raised. (Interesting read, you should take a look).*

When you search for `./fruits/apples/` we get a `"true"` but with `./fruits/` we get a `"false"` with that logic in mind if a user search for `./fruits/` or `./fruits` he should be redirected to a template with all related `fruits` posts or terms, **as this is not default behaviour**, I came up with a case by case solution:

```
<?php add_action( 'template_redirect', 'fallback_custom_taxonomy_fruits' );
function fallback_custom_taxonomy_fruits() {
  $url = $_SERVER[ 'REQUEST_URI' ];
  if ( ! is_tax( 'fruits' ) && substr( $url, -7 ) == '/fruits' || substr( $url, -8 ) == '/fruits/' ) {
    include( get_template_directory() . '/fruits.php' );
    exit();
  };
}; ?>
```

Regarding `substr`, value should match the number of characters your taxonomy slug is equal to WITH dashes. `substr( $url, -7 ) == '/fruits'`

**This is probably not the best way** but it does the job and it is pretty quick. I didn't see any other solution that was working (September 2020).

Where `fruits.php` is your fallback template in case a user search for `./fruits/` or `./fruits`. We take the end of the url to match it against our custom taxonomy slug. This should only happens when `is_tax()` is false `! is_tax( 'fruits' )` and the url matches our taxonomy.

Let's say now that our custom taxonomy is associated with a custom post type called "recipes". We can then use the following to display posts and associated terms for a custom post type on our fallback `fruit.php` template file:

```
<?php
$custom_post_type = 'recipes';
$taxonomy = 'fruits';

$terms = get_terms( $taxonomy );
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
wp_reset_query();
$args = array(
  'post_type' => $custom_post_type,
  'tax_query' => array(
  array(
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'field' => 'slug',
    'terms' => $term->slug,
  ),
), );

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
  echo $term->name.'<br/>';
  while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
  echo '<a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.the_title().'</a><br>';
  endwhile;
};

}; ?>
```

Additionally you also wanted to have the custom post type (CPT) for your custom taxonomy, in your permalink, in front of your taxonomy, to get a structure like so:
`recipes/fruits/apples` where recipes is your custom post type. You can use the rewrite rule upon registering that taxonomy's arguments using the following: `'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'recipes/fruits' ), hierarchical => true, ),`.

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_taxonomy_nowe' );
function custom_taxonomy_nowe() {
  $custom_post_type = 'Recipes';
  $singular = 'Fruit';
  $plural = 'Fruits';
  $labels = array(
    'name' => $plural,
    'singular_name' => $singular,
  );
  $args = array(
    'labels' => $labels,
    'hierarchical' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => strtolower( $custom_post_type.'/'.$plural ), 'hierarchical' => true, ),
  );
  register_taxonomy( strtolower( $plural ), strtolower( $custom_post_type ), $args );
};
```

Our permalink structure should now look like the following

`domain.com/recipes/fruits/apples/ ...`

`domain.com/_custom_post_type_/_taxonomy_/_term_/ ...`

The taxonomy page can now be use as a posts and a taxonomies index.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221750/discussion-on-answer-by-amarinediary-wordpress-dont-see-taxonomy-page).

Comment: amarinediary this is very interesting case, becouse for me as a persone with some SEO expirience it`s natural to go one lvl up and I'm suprisied this is not work that way. I thought this is posible in the WP hierarchy. It would be cool if taxonomy- $ taxonomy.php page would act for taxonomies same as taxonomy- $ taxonomy- $ term.php for the terms. I hope one day the WP programmers they will notice there is a gape that can be filled

Comment: I didn't try to redirect to the `taxonomy-$taxonomy.php` template but i'm guessing it would work as the only thing keeping it from working is the fact that we get a "false" if no terms are against our taxonomy. So instead a redirecting to `fruit.php` you could actually redirect it to the real template `taxonomy-fruits.php` and modify it.

Comment: Ofcoures you solution is very interesting. When I said that, I was only referring to the situation when you trying to reach to domain.com/_cpt_/_taxonomy_/ URL and you get with 404 code response.