# Custom taxonomy return 404, only last create taxonomy 200

Tags: php, wordpress

I have custom post type and 3 custom taxonomy for this custom post type. I rewrite slug for taxonomy. But all taxonomy archive return 404 error, but last taxonomy archive return 200. If I create new taxonomy, last taxomy too be return 404 error and new taxonomy be have code 200. How this fix?

My code:

```
add_action('init', 'main_avto_post_type');


function main_avto_post_type(){

    register_post_type('main_avto', array(
        'labels'             => array(
            'name'               => 'Schools', // Основное название типа записи
            'singular_name'      => 'School', // отдельное название записи типа Book
            'add_new'            => 'Add new',
            'parent_item_colon'  => '',
            'menu_name'          => 'Schools'

        ),
        'public'             => true,
        'publicly_queryable' => true,
        'show_ui'            => true,
        'show_in_menu'       => true,
        'query_var'          => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '/%main-city%', 'with_front' => false ),
        'has_archive' => 'avtoschools',
        'capability_type'    => 'post',
        'hierarchical'       => false,
        'menu_position'      => null,
        'supports'           => array('title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','comments')
    ) );
}



add_action( 'init', 'create_main_avto_taxonomies' );

function create_main_avto_taxonomies(){


    register_taxonomy('main-city', array('main_avto'), array(
        'hierarchical'  => true,
        'labels'        => array(
            'name'              => _x( 'City', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name'     => _x( 'City', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items'      =>  __( 'Search' ),
            'all_items'         => __( 'All city' ),
            'menu_name'         => __( 'City' ),
        ),
        'show_ui'       => true,
        'query_var'     => true,
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '/', 'with_front' => false ),
  
    ));

    register_taxonomy('main_subway', array('main_avto'), array(
        'hierarchical'  => true,
        'labels'        => array(
              'name'              => _x( 'Subway', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name'     => _x( 'Subway', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items'      =>  __( 'Search' ),
            'all_items'         => __( 'All Subway' ),
            'menu_name'         => __( 'Subway' ),
        ),
        'show_ui'       => true,
        'query_var'     => true,
       
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '/', 'with_front' => false ),
    ));


    register_taxonomy('main_district', array('main_avto'), array(
        'hierarchical'  => true,
        'labels'        => array(
            'name'              => _x( 'district', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name'     => _x( 'district', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items'      =>  __( 'Search' ),
            'all_items'         => __( 'All district' ),
            'menu_name'         => __( 'district' ),
        ),
        'show_ui'       => true,
        'query_var'     => true,
        
        'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => '/', 'with_front' => false ),
    ));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you play with the slug of anything, add a custom post type, or a custom taxonomy *... etc*. you should always reset the rewrite rules using `flush_rewrite_rules()`.

> Remove rewrite rules and then recreate rewrite rules. This function is useful when used with custom post types as it allows for automatic flushing of the WordPress rewrite rules (usually needs to be done manually for new custom post types).

- *Source @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/*

Add the following to the top of your `function.php` file. It should fix your `404.php` error problem.

```
<?php /**
* flush_rewrite_rules( bool $hard = true )
* Remove rewrite rules and then recreate rewrite rules.
* $hard (bool) (Optional) Whether to update .htaccess (hard flush) or just update rewrite_rules option (soft flush). Default is true (hard).
* Must be removed before pushing to live.
* @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/flush_rewrite_rules/
*/
flush_rewrite_rules(); ?>
```

Comment: Have you added terms to your taxonomies? In Wordpress custom taxonomies don't have a default taxonomy index page. You always have to search a term against a taxonomy. eg: `domain.com/taxonomy/` = `404.php` ... but `domain.com/taxonomy/term/` = `taxonomy.php` or `archive.php` ... etc. made a post a while back about that here https://stackoverflow.com/a/63907282/3645650

Answer (score 0):

On a similar problem, moving `register_taxonomy()` to happen before `register_post_type()` as [suggested here](https://cnpagency.com/blog/the-right-way-to-do-wordpress-custom-taxonomy-rewrites/) helped me out.